# Как ввести текущую дату через ctime

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>             // ************** Р А Б О Т А Е Т ***************
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
// Описание класса:
class Spisok231{
public:
// Поля:
int i=0;
int number;
string name;
int klass;
int day;
int month;
int year;



void showAll(){


  cout <<"Номер:  "<<number<<endl;
  cout<<"Фамилия: "<<name<<endl;
  cout<<"Класс:   "<<klass<<endl;
  cout<<"Дата:    "<<day<<endl;
  cout<<"Месяц:   "<<month<<endl;
  cout<<"Год:     "<<year<<endl;
  }
};
//лавная функция программы:
int main(){

system("chcp 1251 > nul");

//Создание оъеекта:
Spisok231 obj;
// Присваивани значений полям:
obj.number=1;
obj.name="Иванов Алексей";
obj.klass=231;
obj.day=24;
obj.month=2;
obj.year=2018;
// Вызов метода:
obj.showAll();
// Задржка консольного окна:
system("pause>nul");
return 0;
}



Как ввести текущую дату, месяц и год через ctime
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c И там один из ответов...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime смотрите пример.

Comment: Спасибо, все поправил.